# Installing Trim for new Vinyl Plank Flooring

Tags: drywall, flooring, trim, vinyl-flooring

So it looks like part of my house had the door trim installed after the carpet.  I'm currently in the process of ripping the carpet up and installing vinyl plank flooring, and noticed the huge gaps.  Are my only options replacing all of the trim or caulking the bottom?  Are there other options/products available?
[image: Door Frame Gaps]

I also noticed gaps in this corner of drywall, as well as the drywall sheets touching the slab.  I assume the only reason you don't do this is so that moisture isn't wicked up (given the gypsum does look soft).  I figure I can throw some drywall tape on it and mud it up.
[image: Corner gap]

Lastly, how do you account for the flooring around a curved fireplace?  Is there a way to flush-cut the bottom of the brick, or do you install quarter-round trim at slight angles?
[image: Firewall]

I also assume all of the minor holes/gaps from tearing out the tack-board won't be an issue.

Comment: if you heat up waterproof trim, you can bend it to hug your rounded fireplace corner. I used a heat gun and a section of aluminum duct to make a little "kiln" that fit the trim pieces i needed to bend. You might want to cut out small pie wedges from the bottom back corner to allow it to bend more w/o buckling.

Comment: I had to 3D print a few squat pieces of trim to refurbish some gaps. Once primed, it painted up well and is barely visible even if you know what to look for. I recommend a small chamfer on leading edges to accept painter's caulk to leave an invisible interface.

Comment: Please VTC, this is a duplicate question posted in error. Don't answer it.